# Выведите все ссылки, которые находятся в тегах a:

Tags: python

Выведите все ссылки, которые находятся в тегах `a`:

```
<span><a target="_blank" href="https://stepik.org/">Hyperlink</a><span>
```

Должно вывести: https://stepik.org/
Мой код:

```
import re
s = input()
pattern = r'<a.*href="([^"]+)'
it = re.findall(pattern,s)
print(*it,sep="\n")
```

Из этой строки строки выводится только `./img/tochno.txt`, а следующая ссылка не выводится. Как исправить регулярное выражение?

```
</p></main><footer><a class="link" href="./img/photo.jpg" download="">Фото</a><p class="link">id стикера - CAACAgIAAxkBAAIDxWITCaZnaUelQ0SNlHMTrjd2klAmAAIBAQACVp29CiK-nw64wuY0IwQ</p><a class="link" href="./img/tochno.txt" download="">Документ</a></footer></body></html>
```

Comment: Строка из которой необходимо вывести ./img/photo.jpg и ./img/tochno.txt     выглядит так:                                                                                                              </p></main><footer><a class="link" href="./img/photo.jpg" download="">Фото</a><p class="link">id стикера - CAACAgIAAxkBAAIDxWITCaZnaUelQ0SNlHMTrjd2klAmAAIBAQACVp29CiK-nw64wuY0IwQ</p><a class="link" href="./img/tochno.txt" download="">Документ</a></footer></body></html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использован положительный просмотр назад `(?<=...)`

```
import re

s = '</p></main><footer><a class="link" href="./img/photo.jpg" download="">Фото</a><p class="link">id стикера - CAACAgIAAxkBAAIDxWITCaZnaUelQ0SNlHMTrjd2klAmAAIBAQACVp29CiK-nw64wuY0IwQ</p><a class="link" href="./img/tochno.txt" download="">Документ</a></footer></body></html>'
pattern = r'(?<=<a class="link" href=")[^"]+'
it = re.findall(pattern, s)
print(*it, sep="\n")
```

```
./img/photo.jpg
./img/tochno.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

pattern = r'<a.+?href="([^"]+).+?a>'